# Saving articles and related categories according to normalization

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Saving articles_categories according to normalization

I have three tables

```
  -----------
    articles  
    -----------
    id  int(11) 
    title varchar(100)


-----------
categories
----------
id  int(11)
title varchar(100)


-------------------
articles_categories
--------------------
articles_id  int(11)
categories_id int(11)
```

I want to save it according to normalization rule to achieve like this

```
articles_id  | categories_id
     1                1 
     1                2 
     1                3
```

How can I achieve with code igniter thanks. So far I had already tried like this

View | Create.php

```
<?php echo form_input('title','','id="title_input"'); ?><br>
Category
<?php 
    foreach ($categories as $c)
    {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" id="categories[]" name="categories[]" value="'.$c['id'].'">';
        echo $c['title'].'&nbsp';
        }
?>

    <?php
        echo form_submit('Submit',"Submit");
        echo form_close();
    ?>
```

Controller  | articles.php

```
function insert()
{
    $this->articles_model->save();

}
```

Model | articles_model.php

```
 function save(){
    $title=$this->input->post('title');
    $categories= implode(',',$_POST['categories']); //inputs will be 1,2,3

    $data=array(
         /* missing ideas.............*/
     );

    $this->db->insert('articles_categories',$data);
 }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `id="categories[]" ` explain? :) You need just to create proper SQL statement with JOIN that is all.

Comment: @Robert that's just a way of creating an array from a HTML form. He's outputting a checkbox for every caregory in the database so when you submit the form you'll get an array of category ids

Comment: thanks Thomas.Yes, Robert that is to work with javascript. name="categories[]" is the actual usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you need to first save your article and use `$this->db->insert_id()` to get the id of it.

```
$title = $this->input->post('title');
$data = array('title' => $title);
$this->db->insert('articles', $data);
$article_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Now create a batch operation to insert that id against each of the categories (don't use implode!)

```
$categories = $this->input->post('categories');
$data = array();
foreach($categories as $category_id){
    $data[] = array(
        'articles_id' => $article_id,
        'categories_id' => $caregory_id
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('articles_categories', $data);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks Thomas. I can't vote up as my points are too low but I choosed your as answer.

Comment: Yes you can. The whole documentation can be found here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html lots of helpful info and examples there.

Comment: I usually refer to that bro. Still was unsuccessful. Your solution helped . I ask another questions. Insert, Update, Delete collection . May be it might help other people too. :)