# Normalization , Category Listing and Code igniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, normalization

I have three tables

articles
[image]

categories

[image]

and relationship table articles_categories

[image]

that table is where I store my relationship like this using normalization features.Like this
[image]

I was able to do select,insert,update, delete . Here are my previous questions
[Insert , Update , Delete -> Normalization & Code Igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748287/insert-update-delete-normalization-code-igniter)
[Saving articles and related categories according to normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733325/saving-articles-and-related-categories-according-to-normalization)

What I am trying to achieve now is I am trying to create a listing of articles via category. Like this

```
Category Name
- article relating to that category
- article relating to that category
- article relating to that category
- article relating to that category
```

This is my controller

```
function category($id)
        {
            $data['title'] = "View by category";
            $data['articles_categories']=$this->articles_categories_model->get_by_id($id);
            $data['articles']=$this->articles_model->get();
            $data['category_id']=$id;

            $data['categories_list']=$this->categories_model->get();     
            $this->load->view('articles_pages/category',$data);    
        }
```

My view

```
<?php
    //$category_id;
    foreach($articles as $a)
    {
        foreach($articles_categories as $ac)
        {
            if($ac['categories_id']==$category_id && $a['id']==$ac['articles_id'])
            {
                echo $a['title'];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I can't get the desire result. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Are there multiple categories displayed on the same page?

Comment: single category ->items representing to that category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the category method takes an `$id` as a parameter, I am going to assume that you only want to display articles for a single category.

You are currently returning data that you don't want, and then filtering it out in your view. This is inefficient (and could become a problem as the amount of articles increases), and it is not the correct approach to MVC programming. Instead of returning every article and then filtering through the data, we should concentrate on getting the correct data in the model and passing that to the view.

Controller:

```
function category($id) 
{
   $data['title'] = "View by category";
   $data['articles'] = $this->articles_model->get_articles_by_category(id);
   $data['category_id']=$id;

   $data['categories_list']=$this->categories_model->get();     
   $this->load->view('articles_pages/category',$data);    
}
```

Model:

```
function get_articles_by_category($id) 
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('articles');
   $this->db->join('articles_categories', 'articles.id = articles_categories.articles_id');
   $this->db->where('articles_categories.categories_id', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get();

   return $query;
}
```

In the above we join the articles table, with the articles_categories table, allowing us to get articles from a certain category. The above is just an example using the active-record class, but feel free to re-write it in whichever style your comfortable with.

Comment: sorry that will be my bad, I have templates files such as sidebar,header,footer. Thanks Jeemusu. I will try yours and get back to you asap.